# Flattened pivot table values should be next to each other w.r.t. to column

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

After Flattening I am getting (Completed, A), (Completed, B), (Completed, C) whereas i want it to be (Completed, A), (Not_Completed, A), (Completed, B), (Not_Completed, B).

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'P':['A','B', 'C'], 'id' : ['1100', '1101', '1102'], 'Completed' : [10,4,8], 'Not_Completed' : [6,2,2]})


   P    id  Completed  Not_Completed  

0  A    1100         10            6

1  B    1101          4            2

2  C    1102          8            2

x = x.sort_values(by = 'Completed',ascending = False)
x1 = x.pivot_table(index='id', columns=['P'], values=['Completed', 'Not_Completed'], fill_value = 0)
flattened = pd.DataFrame(x1.to_records())
flattened
```

Actual columns:

```
id (Completed, A), (Completed, B), (Completed, C), (Not_Completed, A), (Completed, B), (Not_Completed, C)
```

Expected columns:

```
id (Completed, A), (Not_Completed, A), (Completed, C), (Not_Completed, C), (Completed, B), (Not_Completed, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort `x1`'s columns before flatten:

```
flattened = pd.DataFrame(x1.sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
                           .to_records())
flattened
```

gives you what you want (given `A, B, C` are in order).

In the case you have a order dict:

```
orders = {'A':10, 'B':4, 'C':8}
```

then you can sort columns by that order:

```
cols = sorted(list(x1.columns), 
              key=lambda x: (-orders[x[1]], x[0]) 
             )

flattened = pd.DataFrame(x1[cols].to_records())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helps in aligning columns but i also want to sort those columns according to 'Completed'.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what do you mean by *sorting columns according to `Completed`*?

Comment: In this question:
'A' has value of completed column as 10 so it should be placed first.
'C' has value of completed column as 8 so it should be placed second.
'B' has value of completed column as 4 so it should be placed third.

This should be ideal order:

id (Completed, A), (Not_Completed, A), (Completed, C), (Not_Completed, C), (Completed, B), (Not_Completed, B)

Comment: @TayyabRahmani see update. Notice the swap of `x[1]` and `x[0]`.

Comment: I have updated the question a little, you can see in the Completed column 'A' has the highest value after that C, then B.
So i was trying to sort according to these first then applying pivot table function.
If possible please help without the creation of dictionary.
Thanks for the help.